# AggregatorV3Interface Error Troubleshooting

Tags: solidity, chainlink, error

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;

// import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";


pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface AggregatorV3Interface {
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

  function description() external view returns (string memory);

  function version() external view returns (uint256);

  function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );

  function latestRoundData()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );
}

contract FundMe{
    mapping(address => uint256) public AddressToAmountFunded;
    function Fund() public payable{
        AddressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x1b44F3514812d835EB1BDB0acB33d3fA3351Ee43);
        return priceFeed.version();

    }
    function getPrice() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x1b44F3514812d835EB1BDB0acB33d3fA3351Ee43);
        (uint80 roundId,
         int256 answer,
         uint256 startedAt,
         uint256 updatedAt,
         uint80 answeredInRound)
         = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
         return uint256(answer);
    }
}
```

And I got this errors

```
[block:34707961 txIndex:3]from: 0x8aB...1BEA3to: FundMe.(constructor)value: 0 weidata: 0x608...20033logs: 0hash: 0xd0a...8ec83
call to FundMe.getPrice
call to FundMe.getPrice errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":3115511435771948}
call to FundMe.getPrice
call to FundMe.getPrice errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":3115511435771994}
call to FundMe.AddressToAmountFunded errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.5.0) (argument=null, value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)
call to FundMe.getPrice
call to FundMe.getPrice errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":3115511435772017}
call to FundMe.getVersion
call to FundMe.getVersion errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":3115511435772020}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues are potentially causing the error.

First of all, you have two `pragma solidity` states, while you just need only one. By using the `pragma` keyword, you are setting the Solidity compiler version(s) which can compile your smart contract.

Second, your constructor is `payable`, which means that you need to provide some amount of native coin during deployment. If I am not mistaken, your value during deployment was set to zero.

Note that the `function Fund() public` syntax is outdated, you should use `constructor()` instead.

Third, the price feed aggregator address is hard coded to `0x1b44F3514812d835EB1BDB0acB33d3fA3351Ee43` which is the BTC/USD aggregator on the Ethereum Sepolia test network. If you are not calling the `getPrice()` function on the Ethereum Sepolia test network, it will revert.

Comment: i appreciate i only just use sepolia network to do that and i works